# Is there a good resource for learning about univariate polynomial equations over the hyperbolic numbers?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, reference-request, book-recommendation, hyperbolic-geometry

Solving equations over the [hyperbolic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) is weird; for example, the equation $x^2 = 1$ has four solutions; not only are $1$ and $-1$ solutions, but so too are $j$ and $-j$.

> **Question.** Are there any good resources out there for learning how to solve polynomial equations over the hyperbolic numbers? I'm especially interested in the problem of finding all $n$th roots of unity.

**Remark.** The familiar formula $$x^2 + bx = (x+b/2)^2-b^2/4$$ holds over any ring in which $2$ has a multiplicative inverse. This means that we can reduce the problem of solving $x^2+bx+c = 0$ to the problem of finding the square roots of $b^2/4-c$.

Comment: The ring isomorphism given in that WP-page reduces the problem of finding $n$th roots of unity in this ring to the same problem in the componentwise ring $\Bbb{R}^2$. In other words, there aren't any more roots of unity. The same approach can be applied to other polynomial equations. They are reduced to a system of two polynomial equations with real coefficients and unknowns.